# Thinking sphinx, has_one association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

anybody, please, help me with Thinking_sphinx configuration.
I have table profile1, which has_one profile2 and profile3.
So i just need to index them both, but i can't.
I tried

```
indexes name
indexes profile2(:name), :as => :profile2_name
indexes profile3(:name), :as => :profile3_name
has id
```

What i m doing wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax seems correct, though you may want to use a symbol for the attribute:

```
has :id
```

How is it not working, though?